# .net image editing algorithms

Tags: .net, image, editing

I want a .net (or native) code that will be able to add a soft borders to an image.

For example:

Initial image

[image]

Image after transformation:

[image]

I did it with Word 2010, but I am sure there is a C++ or .net lib that does the same.

If you are familiar with some code that can do this, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to fade to a color (like white), or using the alpha channel?

Comment: Alpha channel is better of cause, but white would also do.

Comment: You do not start from scratch here. Download Gimp and program it with script fu. See here: http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/gimp/script-fu/script-fu-tut.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out ImageMagick.

http://www.imagemagick.org/index.html

Comment: I have managed to find the required effect in the ImageMagick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to create an image that fades from white to transparent, and just draw that on top of the image. Like:

```
using (Bitmap b = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("frame.png")) {
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(theImage)) {
    g.DrawImage(b, 0, 0, theImage.Width, theImage.Height);
  }
}
```